# Why am I receiving maximum recursion depth exceeded error message?

Tags: django

Please can someone explain why I am recieving the following error?

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: RecursionError
Exception Value:    
maximum recursion depth exceeded
Exception Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in __init__, line 640
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path:    
['Z:\\Development\\Intranet\\Education\\EducationProject',
 'Z:\\Development\\Intranet\\Education\\EducationProject',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual '
 'Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual '
 'Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 25 Jun 2020 20:13:46 +0000



#from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "EducationProject"

urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', views.homepage, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/',views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^aboutcentre/', views.aboutcentre, name='aboutcentre'),
    url(r'^facilities/', views.facilities, name='facilities'),
    url(r'^staff/', views.staff, name ='staff'),
    url(r'^policy/', views.policy, name='policy'),
    url(r'^research/', views.research, name='research'),
    url(r'^teaching/', views.teaching, name='teaching'),
    url(r'^GCSE/', views.GCSE, name='GCSE'),
    url(r'^ALevel/', views.ALevels, name='ALevel'),
    url(r'^University/', views.University, name='University'),
    url(r'^Journals/', views.Journals, name='journals'),
    url(r'^Other/', views.Other, name='other'),
    url(r'^Curriculum/', views.Curriculum, name='curriculum'),
    url(r'^admissions/', views.admissions, name='admissions'),
    url(r'^accessibility/', views.accessibility, name='accessibility'),
    url(r'^employment/', views.employment, name='employment'),
    url(r'^vacancies/', views.vacancies, name='vacancies'),
    url(r'^applicationform/', views.applicationform, name='Application'),
    url(r'^declaration/', views.declaration, name='declaration'),
    url(r'^education/', views.education, name='education'),
    url(r'^postsixteeneducation/', views.postsixteeneducation, name='postsixteeneducation'),
    url(r'^presentemployment/', views.presentemployment, name='presentemployment'),
    url(r'^previousemployment/', views.previousemployment, name='previousemployment'),
    url(r'^gapsemployment/', views.gapsemployment, name='gapsemployment'),
    url(r'^otherinterests/', views.otherinterests, name='otherinterests'),
    url(r'^referee/', views.referee, name='referee'),
    url(r'^signature/', views.signature, name='signature'),
    url(r'^news/', views.News, name='News'),
    url(r'^topnews/', views.topnews, name='TopNews'),
    url(r'^mostpopularnews/', views.mostpopularnews, name='MostPopularNews'),
    url(r'^archives/', views.archives, name='Archives'),
    url(r'^TV/', views.TV, name='tv'),
    url(r'^Radio/', views.Radio, name='radio'),
    url(r'^Books/', views.Books, name='Books'),
    url(r'^RSS/', views.RSS, name='rssfeed'),
    url(r'^Podcasts/', views.Podcast, name='Podcast'),
    url(r'^Podcasts_series/', views.Podcast_series, name='Podcast_Series'),
    url(r'^Podcasts_people/', views.Podcast_people, name='Podcast_People'),
    url(r'^Podcasts_latest_episodes/', views.Podcast_Latest_Episodes, name='Podcasts_Latest_Episodes'),
    url(r'^Podcasts_popular_episodes/', views.Podcast_Popular_Episodes, name = 'Podcasts_Popular_Episodes'),
    url(r'^Business/', views.business, name='business'),
    url(r'^Giving/', views.giving, name='giving'),
    url(r'^Journals/', include('EducationProject.Journals.urls', namespace='Journals')),
    url(r'^Lessons/', include('EducationProject.Lessons.urls', namespace='Lessons')),
    url(r'^Assignments/', include('EducationProject.Assignments.urls', namespace='Assignments')),
    url(r'^Examinations/', include('EducationProject.Examinations.urls', namespace='Examinations')),
    url(r'^Grades/', include('EducationProject.Grades.urls', namespace='Grades')),
    url(r'^Homework/', include('EducationProject.Homework.urls', namespace='Homework')),
    url(r'^Modules/', include('EducationProject.Modules.urls', namespace='Modules')),
    url(r'^Pedagogy/', include('EducationProject.Pedagogy.urls', namespace='Pedagogy')),
    url(r'^Qualifications/', include('EducationProject.Qualifications.urls', namespace='Qualifications')),
    url(r'^Subjects/', include('EducationProject.Subjects.urls', namespace='Subjects')),
    url(r'^ComputerScience', include('EducationProject.Subjects.ComputerScience.urls', namespace='ComputerScience')),
    url(r'^English/', include('EducationProject.Subjects.English.urls', namespace='English')),
    url(r'^Geography/', include('EducationProject.Subjects.Geography.urls', namespace='Geography')),
    url(r'^History/', include('EducationProject.Subjects.History.urls', namespace='History')),
    url(r'^Mathematics/', include('EducationProject.Subjects.Mathematics.urls', namespace='Mathematics')),
    url(r'^PSHE/', include('EducationProject.Subjects.PSHE.urls', namespace='PSHE')),
    url(r'^ReligiousStudies/', include('EducationProject.Subjects.ReligiousStudies.urls', namespace='ReligiousStudies')),
    url(r'^Science/', include('EducationProject.Subjects.Science.urls', namespace='Science')),
]

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'Home.html')
```

I have included urls.py and views.py above.

I'm not sure why this is occurring despite having read other similar articles. I haven't changed anything specific. The articles I have read so far include:

**https://medium.com/bilesanmiahmad/how-to-prevent-recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-when-using-django-signals-dbfe1615eff1**

**[Django/Python Runtime Error: Maximum recursion depth exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892738/django-python-runtime-error-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded)**

[image]

Comment: When you say you "haven't changed anything specific" what does that mean? Was it working before? What does your app structure look like? Some of those includes go down quite a few levels.

Comment: Please see the image I have added above.

Comment: Are each of those folders under Subject separate applications?

Comment: Yes they are separate applications.

Comment: Have you checked your template if you are using a recursive function there?